# Centos root out of disk space. Unable to run du command

Tags: centos, ssh

My centos root is full and I dont know what folder is taking the space

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home     174G    95G     80G     55%     /home
/dev/mapper/centos-root     50G     50G     20K     100%    /
/dev/sda1                   497M    176M    322M    36%     /boot
/dev/sdb1                   3.6T    215G    3.2T    7%      /home2
```

When I tried to us du command, it is returning errors probably because it cannot create temporary files to return the result

```
[root@ds1 /]# du -sh *
0       aquota.group
0       aquota.user
0       backup
0       bin
151M    boot
0       dev
41M     etc
107G    home
215G    home2
0       lib
0       lib64
0       media
0       mnt
du: cannot access ‘proc/1854/task/2088/fdinfo/130’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/1854/task/2088/fdinfo/131’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/1854/task/2088/fdinfo/151’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/1854/task/32439’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/32433/task/32433/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/32433/task/32433/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/32433/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/32433/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/32436’: No such file or directory
0       proc
0       quota.group
0       quota.user
4.0K    razor-agent.log
3.9M    root
49M     run
0       sbin
0       scripts
0       srv
0       sys
```

What other command i can use to find and delete files that is causing the issue?

Thanks

Comment: You ran `du` successfully. Those `No such file or directory` errors are about processes that ended before du could read the contents of their virtual folders.

Comment: @ThoriumBR but it does not show what is causing the 100% use in centos root. what command can i run to see what directory is causing the build up?

Comment: Use `du -sh -x /`, it will show you only the folders for the root partition.

Comment: it only show 13G. my root is supposed to be 50G `[root@ds1 /]# du -sh -x /
13G     /
[root@ds1 /]#`

Comment: Is it safe to reboot system at this state? DB is no longer responding :(

Comment: Probably some file is being held open after being deleted. `lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'` will show you if this is the case. Rebooting will likely corrupt your database, as there are files on cache that could not be written to disk yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you like a curses-based interface to browsing the size of your directories, I recommend `ncdu`.  It also has an `-x` option to stay within one filesystem.

I agree with @ThoriumBR  advise to find deleted files with lsof. Shut those processes down gracefully if possible.

You have mounted a few TB of space at /home2.  If you would also like that space to be used for your database, consider making it into a volume group, and allocating logical volumes for  /home2,  your database directory, and whatever else you need.